# Sequelize model error-tring to make model in sequelize and getting this error

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Error 471--cannot find module!

This is the model I am tring to write.T
have data is already in mysql. Tring to connect from sequilize. I deleted all node module and tried again,nothing is working.Please suggest something.

module.exports = function(sequelize,dataTypes) {

```
var calender = sequelize.define("calender",{

     listing_id:DATATYPE.INTEGER,

      listdate:DATATYPE.DATE, 

      available:DATATYPE.TEXT, 

      price:DATATYPE.TEXT

     });

return calender;
};
```

This is the code

now this is the error

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\mindsumo\dataairbnb\models/..configconfig.json'

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)

at Module.require (module.js:497:17)

at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

at Object.<anonymous> (E:\mindsumo\dataairbnb\models\index.js:8:17)

at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)

at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

at Module.require (module.js:497:17)

at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

at Object.<anonymous> (E:\mindsumo\dataairbnb\server.js:10:11)

at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)

at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)

at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)

at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)

at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
```

Error while making model

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:generate --name calender1 --attributes 
  listing_id:int, listdate:date, available:text, price:text

node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:generate --name calender1 --attributes listing_id:int, lis
tdate:date, available:text, price:text

Sequelize CLI [Node: 6.10.3, CLI: 3.0.0, ORM: 3.30.4]

E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1079
      else throw err
           ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
    at eval (lodash.templateSources[0]:18:32)

    at Array.forEach (native)

    at eval (lodash.templateSources[0]:14:26)

    at Object.render (E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-
   cli\lib\helpers\template-helper.js:26:54)

    at Object.generateFileContent 
    (E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\helpers\model-
    helper.js:31:37)

    at Object.generateFile (E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-
    cli\lib\helpers\model-helper.js:41:49)

    at Object.exports.handler (E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\commands\model_generate.js:32:27)

    at Object.self.runCommand (E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-cli\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:233:22)

    at Object.Yargs.self._parseArgs (E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:990:30)

    at Object.get [as argv] (E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:927:19)

    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\sequelize:84:15)

    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)

    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)


   E:\mindsumo\studyairbnb\node_modules\sequelize-
   cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1079
      else throw err
           ^
```

Comment: post your model

Answer (score 1):

If you used [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework, this example help you a lot:

https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/tree/master/models

I too had problems with Sequelize in the start.

**Check especially:**

- `models/index.js`
- `models/user.js`
- `routes/index.js`