# Sequelize.js save() function gives "has no comperator" Error

Tags: node.js, function, save, runtime-error, sequelize.js

I just came back to a project that which uses Sequelize.js. I had to make some changes and when I tried to test it I got this error:

```
Error: id and 1 has no comperator

at Object._joinKeyValue (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2254:13)
at Object.whereItemQuery (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2091:17)
at Utils.getComplexKeys.forEach.prop (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1944:25)
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.whereItemsQuery (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1942:35)
at Object.whereQuery (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1915:24)
at Object.updateQuery (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:367:19)
at QueryInterface.update (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:936:37)
at Promise.try.then.then.then (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:3593:56)
at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

This happens when I execute the save() function on my instance:

```
client.save().then((result) => {
    console.log('Save was successful');
 }, (error) => {
    console.log(`Failed to save client with id = ${client.id}`);
    console.log(error);
});
```

The error does not make sense at all, I would expect this when you try to find records but not update one using the actual instance..

Sequelize.js version : 4.22.2

**EDIT**

I did notice the error is called in /dialects/abstract.
Shouldn't it be MySQL since I use it? And yes, I did specify mysql when creating the Sequelize instance

**EDIT 2**

So I was asked to show how I define the model, I use a singleton for it, but I decided to make a simple temporary definition to see if it the singleton`s issue like so:

```
let Sequelize = require('sequelize');
  let seq = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USERNAME, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {host: process.env.DB_URL, dialect: 'mysql'});
  seq.authenticate().then((result) => {
    let clientModel = seq.define('client', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        messenger_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        first_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        profile_pic: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        city: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        street: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        house_number: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        flat: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        state: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            defaultValue: "initial"
        }
    }, {
      underscored: true,
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ['messenger_id']
        }
      ]
    });
    seq.sync({force: true}).then((result) => {
      console.log("Database synced at: " + new Date());

    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Error accured during syncing: ", error);
    });
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And as expected, same issue. In fact, I get the same error with finding functions (findOne, findById and etc.). Like for example:

```
clientModel.findOne({where: {messenger_id: event.sender.id}}).then((client) => {
        if(!_.isNull(client)){
            handleMessage(client, message);
        }
        else {
            createNewClient(event.sender.id, message);
        }
    }, (error) => {
    console.log('Error when finding a client');
        throw error;
});
```

I get:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: messenger_id and '1638597395723496' has no comperator
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you show the complete model and how you create an instance.

Comment: @alditis Mhm, it's not that simple, I use a model singleton and define models in separate js files. However, I used this technique with the same singleton and model definition format before and it worked just fine, but I haven't touched this project in months. I indeed checked the model is defined without errors and instance is created as well (considering it does allow me to use the save() function at all). Sequelize.js did get updated a lot since then, but I couldn't find anything related to this issue in the changelog

Comment: My proyect have the version 4.8.2. I'm going to update.

Comment: All case test ok, only one warning about http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators

Comment: @alditis So that means it's not a bug in a new version, I posted how I defined the model, it should be correct

Comment: Extract of code: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8589#issuecomment-341894507

Comment: I put your model in my proyect and run it ok. Review this answer for the structure of your proyect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077815/sequelize-model-error-tring-to-make-model-in-sequelize-and-getting-this-error/47109510#47109510

Comment: I try with: `model.client.findOne({where: {messenger_id: 1}}).then((client) => { console.log('client.id: ' + client.id); ...`

Comment: Try defining your models before you connect to the database. You might also try the new `Sequelize.Op` methods.

Comment: Defining did nothing, You can't use `Op` with save, I did try using it with the `findOne` function with `eq` and I got error: `Cannot ready property IndexOf of undefined`